# Installation problem with Realm in Flutter for IOS platform

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, realm

We started a Flutter project few weeks ago and want to use Realm for local storage. But it’s not working on IOS simulator or real device.

We are using this configuration for Flutter and Dart:

Flutter 3.16.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision ef1af02aea (4 days ago) • 2024-01-11 15:19:26 -0600

Engine • revision 4a585b7929

Tools • Dart 3.2.4 • DevTools 2.28.5

We added the Realm to the pubspec.yaml

realm: ^1.6.1

On Android, Realm is working well and when we want to update the pods and run on IOS, we get this error:

```
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.14.3 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.14.3

Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
project dir is /Users/agusampietro/GitHub/Dems/app/dems_mobile/ios
app dir is /Users/agusampietro/GitHub/Dems/app/dems_mobile
bundleId is dems_mobile
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (1.6.2)
Installing Firebase (10.18.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (10.18.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.18.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (10.18.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMAppAuth (2.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.3.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn (7.0.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.12.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.3.1)
Installing RecaptchaInterop (100.0.0)
Installing firebase_auth (4.16.0)
Installing firebase_core (2.24.2)
Installing firebase_messaging (14.7.10)
Installing flutter_native_timezone (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_share (0.0.1)
Installing geolocator_apple (1.2.0)
Installing google_sign_in_ios (0.0.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.1)
Installing path_provider_foundation (0.0.1)
Installing permission_handler_apple (9.1.1)
Installing realm (1.6.1)
Installing shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1)
Installing the_apple_sign_in (1.0.0)
Generating Pods project
[!] Unable to install vendored xcframework `realm_dart` for Pod `realm`, because it contains both static and dynamic frameworks.
```

We already cleaned the flutter project, deleted the podfile, checked for updates on xcode, flutter and pods. and we could not find the solution for this issue.

Probably someone had this error before. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Krish

Comment: Well, you should include your actual podfile. A number of the libraries bring installed are outdated and as you can see from the message, the Cocoapods is outdated as well. Realm is not installed at all too. Please update your question with the podfile and update your cocoapods.